# How is this JSON import working without an export?

Tags: javascript, json, import

I have a test file with the following import at the top

```
import pizzas from '../data';
```

the data file here is data.json and contains an array of objects, this file has no export anywhere inside it so I was wondering how is the import working as I thought you'd need a matching export.

Comment: It's not supported natively in browsers, but it can work in Node and lots of build systems, which have coded extensions allowing for the direct importing of JSON

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks - so you can import and name the JSON data, without needing to export it? I am running it on the terminal so does that mean the test file is running in node? I thought I would need to use the require syntax for that.

Comment: Probably because of https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/esm.html#esm_experimental_json_modules. Related: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-modules https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4315

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm using node 12.10.0, so I don't understand how it's working. Also just to confirm I understand correctly, you can import and name a JSON data file without needing to export it? - I'm reading the article that was linked to my post to find the answer there but haven't seen that yet.

Comment: You need to use the `experimental-modules` flag to run MJS files, right? Node docs say that `--experimental-json-modules` is required as well for plain JSON to be parsed like that, but it doesn't appear to be necessary, since the JSON gets imported properly without that. Does that mean *any* ESM script in Node supports importing JSON like that? The docs aren't up to date? Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Me neither, I was following a unit testing tutorial and the setup of the code provided is a json data file which is imported into a spec.js test file, I was confused by the process of importing without an export and not needing require. Thanks for your help